# How to find an audio file with its name and label store in a database

Tags: python, postgresql

I created a database with postgreSQL containing tables. My first table store metadata of .wav files which correspond to footsteps sounds:

| name | Label |
| --- | --- |
| 015 | Footstep |
| 457 | Footstep,Slam,Walk |
| ... | ... |

My second table correspond to scream sounds:

| name | Label |
| --- | --- |
| 546 | Scream, Human_voice |
| 457 | Scream, Crying_and_sobbing |
| ... | ... |

The number in the column `name` correspond the name of the file (example: 546 correspond to 546.wav)

Originally, all metadata were contained in a single table.csv which I then sort with Python and Pandas to create tables by label.

Now, using these tables I would like to collect the original .wav file contained in a directory (which contain all audio file) to create 1 directory  per label and store the file .wav in it. I need your help for this step.

Comment: You need to make a SQL query to get data out of the database. Was there a particular problem when you tried to do that?

Comment: The database contains tables with the name of the file, not the file itself, so when I ask to get data out of the DB, I only have numbers, how to  make the link between tables and the directories?

Comment: I don't yet understand what the problem is. Can you show an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to split my directory (which contains all the audio file) in subdirectories sorted by labels